# specify subtree of hosts in ansible using --limit

Tags: ansible

I would like to apply playbook to a subset of hosts.  To all dbservers hosts under 'atlanta', not under 'raleigh

but I cannot figure out how to use --limit to point to a specific subtree of hosts in the inventory

```
 ansible all -i ./testhosts.yml --limit atlanta --list-hosts

  hosts (4):
    host1-atlanta
    host2-atlanta
    host1-raleigh
    host2-raleigh

 ansible all -i ./testhosts.yml --limit 'atlanta:&dbservers' --list-hosts

  hosts (4):
    host1-atlanta
    host2-atlanta
    host1-raleigh
    host2-raleigh
```

what I am hoping to get  is

```
    host1-atlanta
    host2-atlanta
```

(in my case the 'logical' path to the subtree is: all:usa:southeast:atlanta:dbservers)

My example testhosts.yml

```
all:
  children:
    usa:
      children:
        southeast:
          children:
            atlanta:
                children:
                    dbservers:
                      hosts:
                        host1-atlanta:
                          ansible_port: 11022
                          ansible_host: 11.0.1.2
                        host2-atlanta:
                          ansible_port: 11022
                          ansible_host: 11.0.1.3
            raleigh:
                children:
                    dbservers:
                      hosts:
                        host1-raleigh:
                          ansible_port: 11022
                          ansible_host: 10.0.1.2
                        host2-raleigh:
                          ansible_port: 11022
                          ansible_host: 10.0.1.3
        northeast:
        northwest:
        southwest:
```

is it possible to get the --limit command line option to filter out everything, except a particular subtree ?

My higher level ansible invocation scripts already know what site they will operate on, so I was hoping I could somehow have a common hosts file but be able to specify groups using some sort of a tree-navigation 'selector'.

I realize that I could do

```
 ansible atlanta -i ./testhosts.yml --limit atlanta --list-hosts
```

but the problem I am running into with that, is that this type of 'selector' is not available when I use ansible-playbook. 
And the only selector (filter) that I could find was --limit, and that does not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite appearances, groups in ansible are not hierarchical.  You have a single `dbservers` group, and members of that group also belong to both `atlanta` and `raleigh`.  With a small change in your inventory you can get closer to what you want:

```
all:
  children:
    dbservers:
      children:
        dbservers-atl:
        dbservers-ral:
    usa:
      children:
        southeast:
          children:
            atlanta:
                children:
                    dbservers-atl:
                      hosts:
                        host1-atlanta:
                          ansible_port: 11022
                          ansible_host: 11.0.1.2
                        host2-atlanta:
                          ansible_port: 11022
                          ansible_host: 11.0.1.3
            raleigh:
                children:
                    dbservers-ral:
                      hosts:
                        host1-raleigh:
                          ansible_port: 11022
                          ansible_host: 10.0.1.2
                        host2-raleigh:
                          ansible_port: 11022
                          ansible_host: 10.0.1.3
        northeast:
        northwest:
        southwest:
```

With this inventory, each region has a seperate `dbservers-<tag>` group.  There is a global `dbservers` group outside of your region hierarchy that includes *all* `dbservers-<tag>` groups.  With this, you can ask for:

```
ansible all --list-hosts --limit dbservers-atl
```

And get:

```
  hosts (2):
    host1-atlanta
    host2-atlanta
```

Or you can ask for the `dbservers` group:

```
ansible all --list-hosts --limit dbservers
```

And get:

```
  hosts (4):
    host1-raleigh
    host2-raleigh
    host1-atlanta
    host2-atlanta
```

Comment: Thank you @larsks. Looks like the appearance of a hierarchy confused me. You recommendation is right, I will change my config to what you had suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement about the '*--limit*' option is not correct:

> ... this type of 'selector' is not available when I use ansible-playbook.

Quoting from '*man ansible*', or '*man ansible-playbook*':

> -l 'SUBSET', --limit 'SUBSET'
>             further limit selected hosts to an additional **pattern**

Details are available in [Working with Patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#working-with-patterns). For example an equivalent of running ansible

```
ansible all --limit '!dbservers' ...
```

is declaring '*hosts*' in a playbook.yml

```
- hosts: all:!dbservers
```

and running

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml
```

Next equivalent is declaring all '*hosts*' in the playbook.yml

```
- hosts: all
```

and running

```
ansible-playbook --limit '!dbservers' playbook.yml
```